# Is it OK to use a static var and class methods to access an object?

Tags: objective-c

Is it acceptable OO programming in objective-c to use the combination of a class method and a static variable to access an instance of an object? (I believe this is called a singleton?)

For Example:

```
OverlayController.h
@interface OverlayController : NSObject
- (void)doSomething; //instance
+ (OverlayController*)controller; //class
@end

OverlayController.m
#import "OverlayController.h"  

static OverlayController *activeController;
@implementation OverlayController

- (void)show { //equivalent of init
    activeController = self;
}

- (void)doSomething {} //now have access to the object instance

+ (OverlayController*)controller {
    return activeController;
}

@end
```

The object could now be accessed from any context using `OverlayController *controller = [OverlayController controller];`

I haven't come across something like this before and all other code for singletons that I've found has used all kinds of dispatch magic to get things working so I'm wondering if using this code will create any major problems?

Comment: This code has several issues as-is. 1) Where do you alloc/init the singleton? 2) The code doesn't prevent someone from creating other instances and calling the `show` method. That will mess up the setting of `activeController`. The pattern you see using `dispatch_once` is used for a reason.

Comment: Consider describing what you want to use it for as your current sample is a half mutant singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question to a large extent. The fact there is a named Design Pattern for the code structure you've described means that it is perfectly acceptable OO Programming.

Well I say perfectly acceptable, some people don't like Singletons, but they're effective.

Answer (score 0):

What you've discribed is Singleton.

Widely used and a very very good design pattern to use when you allow only a single instance of your object.

Further reading below:

- http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern